# If you could have only one book on web security, what would it be?

Tags: professional-education

If you could have only one book on web security, what would it be?

Comment: Well, now clear. But again - question needs to be specified. There are lot of different fields in security, it is a very wide term. What would you like to hear about - cryptography, web-application security, servers administration, source code analysis and vulnerabilities, deep OS's inspections, user management and policies, etc.? No one good book can cover all the items at once.

Comment: @Ams - once again, edited.

Comment: Still not narrow enough... How to *break* websecurity (i.e. web attacks), or how to *make* it (i.e. secure coding and the like). Or, how to use it, e.g. secure browsing...

Comment: Btw, @Moshe, welcome to the site! Note you might want to wait a while before accepting an answer, especially to a question like this - it will discourage additional answers, which might be even better. Note that this is also quite subjective...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many people do recommend this one book: [The Web Application Hacker's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Flaws](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470170778), which I also find very useful. But you should not rely upon only on one book. This book was released back in 2007 year, now there have appeared many new technologies. So, besides books you should follow standards, RFC's and other documents. I know other really good and fresh book. I have only hard copy in German, not aware if it is available in English - [Sichere Webanwendugen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3836211947).

Comment: By the way, mentioned book highlights : http://portswigger.net/wahh/

Comment: Love this book!

Comment: +1. [Sichere Webanwendungen](http://www.amazon.de/Sichere-Webanwendungen-Praxisbuch-Mario-Heiderich/dp/3836211947) is one of the best, in my opinion. But WebApp Hacker's Handbook is really good as well :)

Comment: second edition available

Answer (score 9):

Since it's now out, my answer would be [The Tangled Web](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/tangled/) by Michal Zalewski.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

For books on how to *build* web security, [Writing Secure Code v2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735617228) from MS Press is still a seminal classic, and even though it was written quite a few years ago by Internet standards, it is still very relevant, and relatively up to date (if no longer complete because of new attack techniques). And it's not just for MS platforms (though many of the newer frameworks are missing)...

Answer (score 6):

Ross Anderson's [Security Engineering](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rja14/book.html) is excellent (and the first edition is currently available online. Some sample chapters from the second edition are online at the time of writing).

Answer (score 4):

I prefer Hunting Security Bugs to The Web Application Hacker's Handbook, but fortunately, you can have more than one book in your life. I have about 40,000.

Comment: you live in a library?

Answer (score 3):

I nice introductionary book to web security I am reading now is [Hacking: The Next Generation](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596154585/).

[image]

It covers a wide range of topics, so maybe it could not be for you if you are looking for something deeper and more focused.

Answer (score 1):

the Web Application Hackers handbook v2 and as a hacker/security guy one book is not what you look for ,also OWASP books are very good in the subject